# Using operator '+' and '*' to statements in C++

Tags: c++, operators, unary-operator

in C++ when i run this code :

```
void main()
{
  2;
  +
  3;
}
```

there is no error
but when i run this code :

```
void main()
{
  2;
  *
  3;
}
```

there is this error:

```
main.cpp:5:3: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
    5 |   3;
      |   ^
```

please someone explain it thanks

Comment: Excuse me, but why do you even need it? In which context expression-level operator is not enough?

Comment: Note that [`void main()` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c). `main` must have `int` return type.

Comment: I really dont get the downvotes. This question is clear and all understand what is asked. the why hinter the question should be blacked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++ is free style language. So space doesn't matter.

In first case it becomes +3 which is a valid statement. [Read Here about `+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

But in second case it becomes *3 which is invalid as compiler thinks you are trying to dereference `3` which is invalid.

Comment: What is a "free style language"?

Comment: I suppose that it means something like "C++ compilers don't care about the amount of whitespace. One single space has the same effect as a thousand newlines and tabs".

Answer (score 10):

Disregard the `2;`, it's a statement on its own that doesn't do anything. Then, if we remove the whitespace, we get

```
+3;
```

Which is a valid expression. Like how `-3;` would also be valid. `+3` is the same as `3`. You can read about the unary plus [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> `+ expression`
>
> unary plus (promotion).
>
> For the built-in operator, expression must
>   have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type. Integral
>   promotion is performed on the operand if it has integral or unscoped
>   enumeration type and determines the type of the result.

`*3`, on the other hand, is not meaningful. Unary `*` can't be applied to the literal `3`.